# Change object's interior opacity

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, transparency, mesh

I added interior for my object using the side property and it reflex the exterior:

```
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to make the interior less accentuated (to change its opacity)? I want to
highlight the fact that the jersey is less colored on the inner side.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the interior less accentuated (to change its opacity)?

Not when you set the `side` material property to `THREE.DoubleSide` since the front and back faces share the same material properties.

I suggest you clone the jersey mesh and use two material like so:

```js
const materialFront = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
const materialBack = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({side: THREE.BackSide});
```

You can then configure the material for the back faces independently of the front faces.